# Get arraylist in arraylist

Tags: c#, casting, arraylist

I have stored one arraylist list into 2nd arraylist and a third arraylist contains 2nd arraylist list.

deliveries arraylist contains list of product and each product list contain list of productdetails.

Now how to get the first productdetails list in deliveries  arraylist.

I tried this but not working

Let suppose I want first enter in productdetails arraylist.

> (
>   (ArrayList)deliveries0[0]
>   )[0].GetValue(1).ToString()

Comment: `ArrayList` is old, you should use `List<T>` instead, and your structure should be a list of custom classes (e.g. delivery) having a Property that is a list of other classes (e.g. product) and so on...

Comment: Unless you are on .Net 1, there's no reason to use ArrayList. List<T> provides everything ArrayList does plus type-safety.

Comment: +1 @digEmAll for custom Class usage

Comment: My question is about casting.

Comment: @Zain: _"i tried this but not working"_ what's the error then ?

Comment: I want to know how to cast each object to arraylist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use LINQ to get the record.

```
var detail = deliveries.FirstOrDefault().ProductDetails.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is often easier to model things as objects:

```
    public class Delivery
    {
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public Delivery()
        {
            Products = new List<Product>();
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public List<ProductDetail> ProductDetails { get; set; }
        public Product()
        {
            ProductDetails = new List<ProductDetail>();
        }
    }

    public class ProductDetail
    {
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
    }
```

You can then create a delivery, product and product description like this:

```
    Delivery delivery = new Delivery();
    Product product = new Product();
    ProductDetail detail = new ProductDetail();
    delivery.Products.Add(product);
    product.ProductDetails.Add(detail);
```

Retrieving the product details is then as simple as:

```
    ProductDetail detail = delivery.Products[0].ProductDetails[0];
```